# What is the name of this game with temples, volcanos and stacking tiles?

Tags: identify-this-game

You build the board with tiles that are 3 hexes joined together, each has a volcano on it. You  stack them, and build stuff on them. Temples on tiles that are 4 high, villages need to have a certain size and there's a third building I can't remember.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you might be talking about [Taluva](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/24508/taluva).

Answer (score 4):

[Tikal](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/54/tikal)

or

**[Java](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/855/java)**

They are both part of the Mask Trilogy of games created by Wolfgang Kramer and Michael Kiesling.  Mexica is the third.

Comment: I played Tikal once and really enjoyed it - certainly matches the description by the OP!